# C++ Cómo poner varias condiciones en el ciclo while?

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa para calcular la hipotenusa en el que eliges la ecuación `1, 2 o 3`; mi ciclo While esta de está forma: `while (select>3)` select es la variable que almacena la respuesta del usuario, para pasar a ejecutar una ecuación (aún no está terminado*/`, lo que deseo es agregar una nueva condición en`while`, la cual no permita al usuario continuar si ingresa el número cero, pues no habría elegido ninguna ecuación, ¿Cómo lo haría? en el código original ya tengo solucionado por si el usuario ingresa una letra, o algo diferente a un entero.

```
    int select=0; // la variable select lee 1, 2 ,3 para realizar la ecuación

    cout << "              \t\t Seleccione el tipo de ecuación que desea solucionar-----" << endl;
    cout << "              \t\t Precione  1.(H^2= Cm^2 + CM^2) 2.(Cm^2= H^2 - CM^2)-----"<<endl;
    cout << "              \t\t -----------O precione 3.(CM^2=H^2 - Cm^2)---------------"; 
    cin >> select;
    int name = 3; 
    int zero = 0;

    //La variable name es sólo un comparativo

    while (select > name ) { // Esto es para que realmente se pueda ejecutar las ecuaciones
        cout << "              \t\t Has introducido algo diferente a 1, 2, 3, try again-----" << endl;
        cin >> select; 

    }
```

Comment: select es la variable donde se guardan tus datos? que es name? completa tu pregunta agregando mas información de tu código y describiendo mejor el problema

Comment: Si, select es una variable

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que leas [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Luego edita tu pregunta e incluye código de lo que has intentado. Mejora la redacción porque tal como está no se entiende. Saludos

Comment: En principio tienes bastantes problemas en la forma que tienes tu código. Creo que necesitas entender un poco mejor el propósito del bucle `while`. Parece que lo quieres usar para todo. Trataré de responderte de la manera más didáctica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero es que no contemplas los números negativos...  tal y como está tu bucle `while`, el programa dará *por bueno* cualquier número negativo... ¿Qué tal se comportará el resto del algoritmo si el usuario introduce `-10`?

Corregir este punto es fácil:

```
while(select < 0 || select > 3)
{
    cout << "\t\t Has introducido algo diferente a 1, 2, 3, try again-----\n";
    cin >> select; 
}
```

Así mismo tampoco tienes en cuenta que el usuario puede *equivocarse* e introducir una letra en vez de un número... en este caso podrás comprobar cómo el programa se vuelve, literalmente, loco.

Este punto se puede corregir así:

```
#include <limits> // std::numeric_limits<>

while( !(std::cin >> select) || select< 0 || select> 3 )
{
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(),'\n');
  std::cout << "\t\t Has introducido algo diferente a 1, 2, 3, try again-----\n";
}
```

Y ya lo tienes, el bucle se repetirá indefinidamente hasta que el usuario introduzca un número comprendido entre el 0 y el 3, ahora solo te queda comprobar cual de los tres valores se ha introducido:

```
switch(select)
{
  case 0:
     // Salir del programa
     break;

  case 1:
     // ...
     break;

  case 2:
     // ...
     break;

  case 3:
     // ...
     break;
}
```

Comment: Gracias, pero, cómo evito que el usuario escriba un 0?

Comment: @PhysicalRam ¿No decías que el 0 sirve para salir del bucle y continuar?

Comment: La verdad, deseo que no pueda introducirlo (el cero) , si no que solo tenga la opción 1,2 o 3 esto es posible?

Comment: @PhysicalRam basta con que modifiques la condición del `while`. `select < 0` pasa a ser `select <= 0`. Y si me aceptas un consejo, estudia más en serio el lenguaje ya que esto es de lo más básico, pero no ya de C++, sino de cualquier lenguaje de programación

Comment: Muchas gracias, soy muy nuevo todavía, aunque reconozco la condición, no la evalúe, Buen aporte!

Comment: @PhysicalRam no te lo tomes como una regañina sino como un consejo. Un saludo